# Using a constant to define a function within a function?

Tags: javascript, function

Main questions:
1. How does f refer to r and t within the formula but no declaration for them anywhere in the code. Also the references appear to be cyclical. 
2. Why is f2 set to f(x) what does that accomplish?

```
let x = 3;
let y = 7;
const f = function(r) { 
        return function(t) { 
              return x + y + Math.abs(r) + t; 
           } 
      };
const f2 = f(x);
x = 2;
alert(f2(17));
```

This code works but I do not understand what it is doing.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: `f` is a function that takes a parameter `r` and returns an anonymous function that takes a parameter `t` and returns the sum of the value of the closed-over variables `x` and `y` and the absolute value of `r` and t. Your code calls `f` with `x` (value == 3) and assigns the returned anonymous function to `f2` then sets `x` to 2 then alerts the result of calling `f2` function with 17. So it's `2 + 7 + |3| + 17` which is 29.

Comment: Thank you. That helps a lot. I have not run into this particular use of functions before.

Comment: NP. You will again though, this is pretty common in every programming language that supports it.

Answer (score 0):

> How does f refer to r and t within the formula but no declaration for them anywhere in the code.

You can declare variables using function arguments. This is what they are doing here.

A simplified example:

```js
function example(f) {
    console.log("f is " + f);
}

example("one");
example(2);
```

> Why is f2 set to f(x) what does that accomplish?

It calls `f(x)` and assigns its return value.

That return value is the function after the `return` keyword.

Now `f2` is a function.

See also [How do closures work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work)